# Is quoting filenames enough security for running `xargs sudo rm -rf`?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, security, rm

I wrote a script that deletes all except the last two files in a folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -1 --quoting-style=shell-always /path/to/some/folder \
    | head -n -2 \
    | xargs printf -- "'/path/to/some/folder/%s'\n" \
    | xargs sudo rm -rf
```

This script will be executed as a cron job every day.

The reasoning is as follows:

1. Obtain a list of all files using `ls -1` (so that I get one file per line);
2. Remove the last two from the list using `head -n -2`;
3. Since `ls` prints relative paths, use the `xargs printf` thing to prepend the folder path and make it an absolute path;
4. Send them to `sudo rm -rf` using `xargs`.

Everyone has access to this folder, so anyone can create and delete any files in this folder.

**The problem is:** `sudo rm -rf` is scary. `xargs sudo rm -rf` is incredibly scary.

I want to be sure that no one can damage other folders/systems by creating clever files to be deleted (either accidentally or on purpose). I don't know, something clever like:

`file with / spaces.txt`

which could result in a super scary `sudo rm -rf /`.

**EDIT:** My mistake, file names cannot contain `/`, so this specific problem wouldn't happen, but the question about whether or not there are other risks still stands.

This is why I am using `--quoting-style=shell-always`, this should prevent any tricks with files with spaces. But now I am wondering if someone could be extra clever with spaces *and* quotes in the filename, perhaps.

**Is my script safe?**

---

Note: I need `sudo` because I am acessing the folder remotely (from a mapped network drive using `mount`), and I couldn't get it to work without sudo.

Comment: Have you considered doing something like `printf -- '%s\0' /path/to/some/folder/* | head -zn -2 | xargs -0 rm`?

Comment: Can a file with the character `/` in the name be created I am trying to achieve this back here

Comment: @George No, a filename cannot contain a slash.

Comment: So when OP says clever person I was wondering...

Comment: Simply because you're parsing `ls` output this is already a poorly written command, even with quoting. `ls` also uses locale for sorting order, I think, so I don't see what's the purpose of `head` in removing last 2 ( unless you're trying to get rid of `.` and `..` which iirc aren't allowed as arguments to `rm` anyway. Just use `find /path/to/folder -type f delete`.  And no `sudo` if you run from cron - cron is already at root level

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I don't know what you mean about `.` and `..` since they would be the first two and not the last two. Also, `ls` does not output `.` and `..` anyway. Also, you should add that as an answer :) Thanks for the suggestion about the usage of `find`, I'll take a look.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Oops, indeed. My mistake haha, thanks for the heads up. So the specific problem I was worried about wouldn't happen anyway - although other risks could be possible so thankfully the question is still valid :)

Comment: Possibly slightly related [Move only the last 8 files in a directory to another directory](//askubuntu.com/q/849792)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Linux, any character is a valid filename constituting character except:

- `\0` (ASCII NUL): as used for string termination in C
- `/` (forward slash): as used for path separation

So, your approach will definitely not work in many cases as you can imagine e.g. does it handle a newline (`\n`) in filename? (*Hint:* **No**).

Few notes:

- Don't parse `ls`; use dedicated tools (there is at least one for most use cases)
- When dealing with filenames, try to leverage the NUL separated output provided by almost all GNU tools that work with such data
- Take care when piping, make sure both programs can understand NUL separations
- Whenever you're invoking `xargs`, see if you can get away with `find ... -exec`; in most cases, you will be fine with just `find` alone

I think these will get you going for now. [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) already provided the NUL separated idea in the comment (`printf -- '%s\0' /path/to/some/folder/* | head -zn -2 | xargs -0 rm`), use this as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I think you should quote steeldriver's comment instead of just mentioning (since comments are not permanent). I will take a look into `find` as well, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have one question though: I don't understand what you mean by "your approach will not definitely work in many cases as you can imagine" - "not work" as in "not safe" or "not unsafe"? Because "your approach" refers to me and not to the malicious user, and your prior statements are in my favor, so I am confused.

Comment: @PedroA You are _you_ :) Like i said, as all characters are valid except the mentioned two, you should be able to imagine the numerous cases your `ls` parsing approach would fail e.g. did you take into account a newline in filename?

Comment: Oh, a newline in the filename... I hadn't thought of that. If you don't mind adding that to your answer too :) Also, sorry to ask, but what does `head -z` do? It sounds ridiculous but I don't have `man` nor `info` in my CoreOS container linux... Couldn't find in the internet either. I get `head: invalid option 'z'`

Comment: @PedroA Newline is just one case, there are many such *as you might have guessed*. You need GNU `head` (comes with GNU `coreutils`). Here's the online version: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/head.1.html

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is I can't install anything else on this CoreOS container linux, so I'll have to search for another approach. But this is getting off-topic, so don't worry.

Comment: Fun fact: I realize now that I should have asked this in "Unix & Linux" SE and not Ask Ubuntu. Oh well.

Comment: @PedroA The theory remains the same though. Perhaps you should now ask how to get GNU tools or create stuffs having similar behavior (remain POSIX).

Answer (score 3):

`xargs` does support some quoting: with single quotes, double quotes or backslash which allows it to accept arbitrary arguments¹, but with a syntax that is different from the Bourne-like shells' quoting syntax.

The GNU implementation of `ls` as found on Ubuntu doesn't have any quoting mode that is compatible with the `xargs` input format.

Its `ls --quoting-style=shell-always` is compatible with ksh93, bash and zsh shells quoting syntax, but only when the output of `ls` is interpreted by the shell in the same locale as `ls` was when it output  it. Also, some locales, like those using BIG5, BIG5-HKSCS, GBK or GB18030 should be avoided.

So with those shells, you can actually do:

```
typeset -a files
eval "files=($(ls --quoting-style=shell-always))"
xargs -r0a <(printf '%s\0' "${files[@]:0:3}") ...
```

But that has little advantage over:

```
files=(*(N))                 # zsh
files=(~(N)*)                # ksh93
shopt -s nullglob; files=(*) # bash
```

The only case where it becomes useful is when you want to use the `-t` option of `ls` to sort the files by mtime/atime/ctime or `-S`/`-V`. But even then, you might as well use `zsh`'s:

```
files=(*(Nom))
```

for instance to sort the files by mtime (use `oL` for `-S`, and `n` for `-V`).

To remove all but the two most recently modified regular files:

```
rm -f -- *(D.om[3,-1])
```

---

<sup>¹ there are still some length limitations (by `execve()` and in some non-GNU `xargs` implementations much lower arbitrary ones), and some non-GNU `xargs` implementations will choke of input that contains sequences of bytes not forming valid characters.</sup>